# Error product category position resets to 1

Tags: magento2, category-products, position, default-values, magento2.3.6-p1

I have a script that sets a position for every product per category, by editing the `catalog_category_product` table.

It runs well and seems to be working, but Magento resets all values every few hours to 1 (default value).
There's no other script that I can find that changes this, and it's not consistent on timings either (sometimes it is at 2 am, others 6 pm, it doesn't matter)

Does anyone have a clue what could be happening?

I'm on **Magento 2.3.6-p1**.

Thanks